# Настройка порта для подключения по ssh Ubuntu

Tags: ssh, маршрутизация, vps

Я пытаюсь подключиться к удаленному `VPS` по `SSH` таким способом:

```
$ ssh root@2a0***********ipV6***6
ssh: connect to host 2a0***********ipV6***6 port 22: No route to host
```

Пробовал `netstat -r` получаю пустую таблицу не доной записи. Хотел добавить `rote add default 2a0***********ipV6***6` . Но похоже тут нужен маршрут(но я пока не пойму что такое маршрут). А где его взять не понимаю. В общем нужно подключиться но не получается. Объясните пожалуйста как это делается и почему. Спасибо.

**UPDATE_1**

Добавил `iptables -I INPUT -p TCP -s 5.******* -j ACCEPT`
При `iptables -L INPUT -n -v --line-numbers`

Получаю вот такую таблицу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Похоже что не 1 раз добавил так у всех записей оди `ip`.
Но при попытке подключения по прежнему

```
$ ssh root@2a03:a0e0:bad:bad::56 -p22
ssh: connect to host 2a03:a0e0:bad:bad::56 port 22: No route to host
```

Comment: Порт точно правильный? В список доверенных ip внесли `iptables -I INPUT -p TCP -s YOUR_CLIENT_IP -j ACCEPT`?

Comment: @Suvitruf нет не вносил. А как узнать значение `YOUR_CLIENT_IP` подскажите пожалуйста. Мне мой провайдер все время разные дает если я правильно понял что это ip машины с которой я собираюсь по ssh подключаться. А если нет то поясните пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Comment: Да, ваш внешний IP. Можете его узнать с помощью сервисов вроде https://www.whatismyip.com/

Comment: @Suvitruf добавил однако ответ все тот же No route to host вероятно это еще не все.